# Date filtering in Linq

Tags: linq

Hi I'm trying to filter my result with a date.

What I tried so far:

```
var lastYear = (DateTime.Now.Year) - 1;
var salesLastYear = _documentService.GetDocuments(
              d => d.DocumentTypeId == saleDocumentId &&
              d.EffectiveOnUtc.Contains(lastYear))
             .Select(d => d.Id).ToList();

var salesLastYear = _documentService.GetDocuments(
              d => d.DocumentTypeId == saleDocumentId &&
             (d.EffectiveOnUtc.Year == lastYear))
             .Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

Both gave no errors in visual studio, but did raise an exeption during execution.
Also tried to convert both the values to a string, but that also failed.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: What does `_documentService.GetDocuments(..)`  return (type)? What is type of `EffectiveOnUtc`? What exception do you have? Have you tried `d.EffectiveOnUtc.Date == lastYear`?

Comment: I doubt that the first compiles, if `EffectiveOnUtc` is a `DateTime`, as the second query suggests, there's no `Contains` method. What type is `EffectiveOnUtc` actually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on the assumption that your `EffectiveOnUtc` is a `DateTime`, and you want to filter to records within the previous calendar year:

```
int lastYear = DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(lastYear, 1, 1);
DateTime maxDate = minDate.AddYears(1);

var salesLastYear = _documentService.GetDocuments(
    d => d.DocumentTypeId == saleDocumentId 
    && d.EffectiveOnUtc >= minDate
    && d.EffectiveOnUtc < maxDate)
    Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Before I could add the answers to all the comments, this turned out to be the answer I was looking for! Thank you.